# PreCss @import variables

Tags: css, variables, import, gulp, postcss

I am currently setting up a new workflow and I decided to try out PostCSS. 
Everything is working fine except one thing only.
I separated my work within several css files. When working on the main css, I import (with Precss) a CSS that contains variables (with Postcss-simple-vars).
When running my Gulp task, I get an error in the terminal basically stating that it failed resolving the variable "$x" or whatever variable I declared in my _variables.css. 
Anyone knows why I can't import variables with Precss?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when setting up a new project recently. It was working fine in my old projects.

I use "precss" instead of "postcss-simple-vars", and my new project was using version 3. My old project was using version 2.

I updated package.json to 
"precss": "^2.0.0"

And everything worked fine again

Answer (score 0):

Used https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-variables-loader. 
Its is Working fine. Just make sure you keep this config css file excluded from your css pipeline.

`exclude: /\.config.css$/,`

and have

`{
  test: /\.config.css$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader!postcss-variables-loader'
}`